# problems with request in a embed form

Tags: forms, symfony

HEllo sorry but my english isnt good.

I'm developing an application in Symfony 2.3.6 where i have to save in a DB (postgres) the values from a user.
The problem happens when my embed form (pais + region) that has 2 submit buttons the user press the second button. The system throw

```
Child "salvar_region" does not exist.
```

The question is how can I detect if the second button is being pressed if the system is throwing an exception?

Here is my Default controller

```
 public function addLocalAction(Request $request)
    {
        $region = new Region();
        $localidad = new Pais();
        $localidad->setRegion($region);
        $form = $this->createForm(new localidadType(), $localidad);  
         if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            $form->getData();    




       if ($form->get('salvarPais')-> isClicked()){
        $objeto = new Pais();
        $objeto->setNombrePais($form->get('nombrePais')->getData());            
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($objeto);
        $em->flush();}

       if ($form->get('salvarregion')->isClicked()){

        $objeto = new Region();
        $objeto->setNombreRegion($form->get('nombreRegion')->getData());
        $objeto->setNombreRegion($form->get('numeroRegion')->getData());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($objeto);
        $em->flush();}



        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('localidades'));


  }
    return $this->render('plataformaPlataformaBundle:Default:localidades.html.twig', array('form'=> $form->createView()));
}
```

My html.twig

```
<form action="{{ path('localidades')}}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
<h3>Agregar País</h3>
<div class="pais">
    {{ form_row(form.nombrePais) }}
    {{ form_row(form.salvarPais) }}
</div>
```

```
<form action="{{ path('localidades')}}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <h3>Agregar Region</h3>

    <div class="region">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form)}}
            {{ form_row(form.region.nombreRegion) }}
            {{ form_row(form.region.numeroRegion) }}
            {{ form_row(form.region.pais) }}
            {{ form_row(form.region.salvarregion) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}

    </div>    

</form>
```

and my 2 type forms

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nombreRegion', 'text', array('label' => 'Nombre de Región: '));
    $builder->add('numeroRegion', 'integer', array('label' => 'Número de Región: '));
    $builder->add('pais', 'entity', array('label' => 'País al que pertenece: ',
        'class' => 'plataformaPlataformaBundle:Pais',
        'property' => 'nombrePais'));
    $builder->add('salvarregion', 'submit', array('label' => 'Guardar Región'));
    $builder->getForm();

}


  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nombrePais', 'text');
    $builder->add('salvarPais', 'submit', array('label' => 'Guardar País'));
    $builder->add('region', new regionType());
    $builder->getForm();

}
```

PD: A lot of thanks if someone can help me 
PDx2: here is an example of the URL request:{"region":{"nombreRegion":"ewrew","numeroRegion":"4","pais":"3","salvarregion":""},"_token":"853d5460b076e01fdf4cef4c59c33e836ab64af3"}

Answer (score 0):

The error you got doesn't look like the name you gave the button during the builder process.

Anyway, to tell if a specific submit was clicked you can use:

```
if($form->get('salvarregion')->isClicked()) {

}
```

Comment: uhm. Was an typping error in the question...This was in my code. The question is how can i get the real name of the button because i tried with region.salvarregion, localidad.region.salvarregion but this doesnt works.